# JQuery on_click: removeClass in a button then toggleClass another (only one button has the class)

Tags: jquery, css, loops, class, onclick

my for each loop button:

```
<td class="p-0 btn-category-list-col">
   <button type="button" value="${cat.category_id}" data-id="${cat.category_id}" class="category_sort btn float-left" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#createCategory">${cat.category_name}</button>
</td>
```

on click code. only showing the relevant lines for the question

```
        $(document).on('click', '.category_sort', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
            let id = event.target.dataset.id;
                if (id) {
                    $(`button[data-id=${id}]`).toggleClass("btn-category-list-col-click");
                }
        });
```

The class gets toggle when running the code above but when I click on another button, the previous button still has the class as expected due to the `toggleClass`

[image: 1]

I would like the previous button to have the `btn-category-list-col-click` taken out and have the newly clicked button to get it.

I tried stacking `removeClass` then `toggleClass` first but the class still stays:

```
            let id = event.target.dataset.id;
                if (id) {
                    $(`button[data-id=${id}]`).removeClass("btn-category-list-col-click");
                    $(`button[data-id=${id}]`).toggleClass("btn-category-list-col-click");
                }
```

Comment: You are not targetting all other elements... `$(".category_sort").removeClass("btn-category-list-col-click");` will remove the class on every `.category_sort` elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `each`, scroll through all the elements that have the `.category_sort` class and delete the `btn-category-list-col-click` class from them, then add it to the current object of the `btn-category-list-col-click` class.

```
$(document).on('click', '.category_sort', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".category_sort").each(function() {
       $(this).removeClass("btn-category-list-col-click");
    });
    $(this).addClass("btn-category-list-col-click");
});
```

Comment: I see, so the key is `.each` thanks for the tip ill keep note of this

Answer (score 0):

```js
//btn-category-list-col-click

$(document).on('click', '.category_sort', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".category_sort").removeClass("btn-category-list-col-click");   
    $(this).addClass("btn-category-list-col-click");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="p-0 btn-category-list-col">
      <button type="button" class="category_sort">cat.category_name1</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="p-0 btn-category-list-col">
      <button type="button" class="category_sort">cat.category_name2</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="p-0 btn-category-list-col">
      <button type="button" class="category_sort">cat.category_name3</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="p-0 btn-category-list-col">
      <button type="button" class="category_sort">cat.category_name4</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```